# How i can have drawing view as a subview of UIPageController when pagination is disabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, draw

i am using **UIPageController** to my project , i want to have drawing view to edit each page , but i want to disable pagination when editing state is active. **Drawing view** is a subview added to **UiPageController.view** , and when i try to disable turning the page , **touchesBegan** and **touchesMoved** did not work .

I am using this code to disable turning page:

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in 
self.pageController.gestureRecognizers)
    {
        recognizer.enabled = NO;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling all gesture recognizers do the following:

```
func disabledPagination() {
    for view in self.pageViewController.view.subviews {
        guard let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView else { continue }
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
    }
}
```

This will just disable the scroll view responsible for pagination.

Comment: I try this , but still pagination was active and does not allow to draw.